# Participating in training courses, even if I am not sure if I want to stay

Tags: professionalism, ethics, quitting, training

My boss wants to send me to a costly external training (all cost covered by the company). I like the topic, and I believe this training could be interesting and beneficial. Unfortunately however I generally do not really feel myself happy at the company. I get tasks that I am able to solve only with enormous struggle, and sometimes  I am not able to solve them at all. So I decided to wait for my next project, if it turns out to be as hard as the most recent ones, I will quit. The training in question might be beneficial, might improve some aspects, but with a project as complex as ours *definitely* can't solve everything. If I take the training and a month later I quit the job, I feel myself bad (and unfair). On the other hand I might get just lucky, maybe this next project is not as hard as the most recent ones (earlier I had some pleasant ones) so I can stay and work within my comfort zone, and then the training might come handy... So my question is how to explain this situation to my boss.

Comment: You left out how long you've been at the company and I think that's a key piece of information. If you turn up for 2 months, go on an expensive course and leave that's different to a longer term employee happening to go on a course towards the end of their time with the company. That said, you're not even sure either way and you definitely don't have a job lined up so I don't see anything unethical in going on a course as *requested*. Asking for an expensive course would probably be wrong, however.

Comment: So far I have spent 25 months with this company

Answer (score 4):

As you've been with the company for over two years and have no actual plans to leave, then I don't see anything unethical with going on a course which is mandated by your boss.

I'd feel a little differently* if you had something else lined up or concrete plans to hand in your notice soon, but right now, although you're dissatisfied, you're sticking with the company. You might find a job soon after and so be it, that's life and business - but it's just as likely that you'll stay for another 6+ months.

To firm up this opinion is the fact that this training may be beneficial to how you feel about this role - it's highly plausible that your boss knows full well you're struggling and/or dissatisfied and is sending you on this course for precisely this reason.

So, in conclusion, go on the course and see what the future brings!

*I should point out that even if it were a little unethical, I'm not actually sure what you could do differently. It's a pretty common rule to never ever show your hand until you're absolutely ready to hand in your notice, anyway.

Comment: to make things even more awkward I have to add that we are a really small company, basically it is only me and him...